# Error casting Object to int

Tags: java, android, serialization, casting

I have a Java server and an Android Client.
The server sends the dimension of a file to the client.
The client receives the object in.readObject().

I need to cast the object returned by in.readObject() to int.
If I do

```
int filesize = (Integer) in.readObject()
```

there are no problems at compile time but Android client execution stops without error or warnings. If I try logging the object received it displays the file dimension sent correctly.

Comment: Have you tried in.readInt(); ?

Comment: What is the class returned by the in.readObject()?

Comment: Try Integer.valueOf(in.readInt());

Comment: How did you *write* the data? Until you answer that we are all just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get object as response from stream. First you need to cast to object then type you want to.

```
Object tempObject =  (Object)in.readObject() ;

   int filesize = Integer.valueOf(tempObject.toString());
```

Comment: @assylias: Ok, changed to String.

Comment: Not the best solution, but can work... By the way, there is no need to cast to Object.

Comment: @assylias: I remember doing something like this at some point. If I am wrong happy to remove my answer.

Comment: @Gilberto: Yes, not best solution, but I remember something like this worked.

Comment: @Hoconosc: If it does, you will see exception stack. Please update question with exception stack.

Comment: Edit: it looks like it's working. Can you explain why this happens only if I use Android?

Comment: May be your readObject() returning empty? In that case, you will get NumberFormatException.

Comment: Nope, it contains the integer I write using out.writeObject() on server side .

Comment: Hmmm, then it should work. With out seeing exception stack, it is hard to guess.

Comment: It does work using your code (I'm about to accept your answer) but it doesn't work if I cast directly to Integer as I've always done in my Java apps (not Android ones).

Comment: @Hoconosc If this works you must have written the number as a String, not an Integer.